# Alamofire multipart upload post error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image-uploading, alamofire

When i tried to upload image using Alamofire  I'm getting error in .POST

Im attaching an image along with this to show the error

(http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/422237/0d5fe4a4b486b14fdf52f8ca26d22bea)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem , as Michal said it's an installation issue if you are using `cocoapods` go to your project `files/pods/Alamofires/Source` and make sure you have 9 files there just like this image and make sure that the `MultipartFormData.swift` file is there

[image]

if you are not using `cocoapods` just open the `Alamofire` folder and go to source folder and make sure you have the same files there too

if you didn't find `MultipartFormData.swift` that means that your Alamofire version does not support MultipartFormData then you will need to get the latest version from here [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) or if you use `cocoapods` you will have to update the line of `Alamofire` `pod` on `podfile` to be like this

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'ProjectName' do

pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'master'

end
target 'ProjectNameTests' do
end
```

after updating your pod file you need to run this command to update the cocoapods project

```
pod install --verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be an installation issue with Alamofire. Check that you have imported it properly.

Changing `.POST` for `Alamofire.Method.POST` or `Method.POST` (if you're also targeting iOS 7 and you didn't import Alamofire as dynamic framework) will reveal the real issue or fix your problem.

Check out [this thread](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/169). Also don't forget that again, when supporting iOS 7, you do not call Alamofire methods with the `Alamofire.` keyword.

Comment: i tried it but still not working any can you give me an example for this?

Comment: Did the error alter? When you entered `Alamofire.Method.POST` or `Method.POST` what was the error displayed by the compiler?

Comment: @Michal, When i made the changes the error came at Alamofire
Can you give me an example how you did it please?

Comment: I'd like to help you but you need to tell me what kind of error appeared when you changed it.

Comment: @Panda Are you able to solve that error? i have the same issue and could not find the solution.