# Alamofire upload image with multipart/form-data

Tags: php, ios, swift, multipartform-data, alamofire

i am looking for a working sample code to upload an image with multipart/form-data using Alamofire

i can't get this code to work with my project

```
Alamofire.upload(
    .POST,
    URLString: "http://httpbin.org/post",
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: unicornImageURL, name: "unicorn")
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: rainbowImageURL, name: "rainbow")
    },
    encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .Success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { request, response, JSON, error in
                println(JSON)
            }
        case .Failure(let encodingError):
            println(encodingError)
        }
    }
)
```

This code has this error `Could not find member 'POST'`

some people said that if you use `Alamofire.Method.POST` it will fix the issue but i got this error instead `Cannot invoke 'upload' with an argument list of type '(Method, URLString: String, multipartFormData: (_) -> _, encodingCompletion: (_) -> _)'`

if anyone has explanation for this error or have another working sample , would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was cocoapods installation issue i had to update the podfile to be like this

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'ProjectName' do

pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'master'

end
target 'ProjectNameTests' do
end
```

so that i can get the latest version of Alamofire that support `MultipartFormData`

for more information see this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31534211/alamofire-multipart-upload-post-error-in-swift/31568570#31568570)