# Multipart form-data file uploading using Alamofire

Tags: swift, multipart, alamofire

I have looked at questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31545620/alamofire-upload-image-with-multipart-form-data) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31534211/alamofire-multipart-upload-post-error-in-swift) one but it is still not working.
[image]

Also I have a question about what should I enter into `fileURL` param from function `multipartFormData.appendBodyPart`?

Should it be a way to image from PC, or image must be added to Images.xcassets? What should I send here?

Comment: Please be more clear about what your question is.

Comment: Dont you see an error on the picture?

Comment: Yes but it would help to include your question in the title or in the body and not expect people to deduce it from the image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you have three issues that you need to fix.

1. Use `.POST` instead of `POST`.
2. The `fileURL` needs to be a valid `NSURL` that points to a file on the file system. You cannot just use the filename.
3. You are using the `responseString` serializer, but named the third parameter in the closure `JSON`. Then you are letting `result` into `s` and trying to print it out. The `result` parameter doesn't even exist anywhere. Instead, you should `print(JSON)`.

Hopefully that helps clear things up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.POST` not `POST`

---

As an alternative solution upload an encoded file and send it as a parameter of POST.

```
// `data` is NSData
let base64String = data!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.allZeros)

let parameters = ["image_data": base64String] as [String: AnyObject]
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://your-url.com", parameters: parameters)
```

The cons of this method is that the data will get %33 larger due to encoding. If you have bandwidth problems it may not be a good solution.

Comment: How to upload an array of base64 Strings?

Comment: Interesting. If the array length is constant just do the same thing with multiple parameters.

Comment: Can you please check this question of mine ?

Comment: @G.Abhisek  I agree with the solutions. Use MultipartPostRequest or alternatively you can upload the images to something like AWS S3 after completion send a request to the server to check x,y,z id's from AWS S3. But still MultipartPostRequest would be the best solution.